# vlc part of desktop streaming to <host>:<port>

Tags: udp, vlc-media-player, wireshark

With VLC, I wish to stream a portion of the desktop and send it to another host on my local area network.

The capture seems to work, I see a correct portion of the desktop into the VLC server, but nothing is send to the network, as Wireshark is empty with the filter `ip.src==192.168.1.31 && udp.port==2416`:

[image: Capture works well]

**Server.bat**

```
vlc -vvv screen:// :screen-fps=15 ^
:screen-top=12 :screen-left=4 :screen-width=320 :screen-height=200 ^
:sout=#transcode{acodec=none}:duplicate{dst=std{access=udp{ttl=1},dst=192.168.1.7:2416},dst=display} ^
:sout-keep
```

**Client.bat**

```
vlc udp://:2416
```

Options in `vlcServer.bat` and `vlcClient.bat` are missing and/or wrong, do you known how correct them?

Comment: So you say with VLC server and java client you receive something?  You could use wireshark to determine if nothing if VLC receives nothing, or if VLC simply "is displaying" nothing...

Comment: I have deployed my test on two computers and used Wireshark, the server doesn't send anything :-(

Comment: did the java client ever receive anything then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, after a lot of tests, I've discovered I need an encoder for screen source:

**vlcServer.bat**

```
@start /MIN "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" ^
-vvv screen:// :screen-fps=25 :screen-top=545 :screen-left=232 :screen-width=250 :screen-height=120 ^
--sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264,acodec=none,fps=25}:rtp{dst=192.168.1.31,port=5004,mux=ts,ttl=1} :sout-keep
```

**vlcClient.bat**

```
@start /MIN "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" rtp://:5004
```

As you can see, the encoder used is H264 for the video, none for the audio.

And now, I've a performance issue... because the observed frame rate is very, very, low

**EDIT**

I've just added `fps=25`. The frame rate is now correct but the latency is about 3 seconds.
It's not acceptable for me, because the image streamed is the artificial horizon of a simulated plane cockpit (X-Plane).

[image]

**EDIT 2**

I've just found a wonderfull X-Plane plug-in which fulfill exactly my needs : [XHSI](http://xhsi.sourceforge.net/). Performances are provided because the information transmitted are not video frames but logical information used to draw images on the target hosts.

Comment: Does it use 100% cpu? You could also try ffmpeg I suppose, which may be more efficient, possibly...

Comment: No, the latency is more a buffer management (threshold watermarks) than a performance issue.

Comment: I know with dshow you can specify the buffer size, dunno about screen input.  Also related: http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/StreamingGuide#Latency and http://betterlogic.com/roger/2010/07/how-to-use-vlc-as-a-free-open-source-alternative-to-playon-tv gl!

Comment: [Ticket opened at ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/ticket/2361)